# display and value depending options of drop down menus with different values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, database, drop-down-menu

I want to submit my selected value in the dropdown menu to my database, but the value that is added to the database is not the same as what I chose.

This is the record that was inserted, and the "kuarter" field value is "kuching-01":
[image]

But these are the selections I chose, where the field "kuarter" is "JALAN DURIAN BURONG STAMPIN":

[image]

How do I add the value "JALAN DURIAN BURONG STAMPIN" to the database instead of "kuching-01"?

This is my javascript:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

var $options = $("#kuarter").clone(); // this will save all initial options in the second dropdown

$("#kawasan").change(function() {
var filters = [];
if ($(this).val() == "") {
  $(this).find("option").each(function(index, option) {
    if ($(option).val() != "")
      filters.push($(option).val());
  });
} else {
  filters.push($(this).val())
}
$("#kuarter").html("");

$.each(filters, function(index, value) {
  $options.find("option").each(function(optionIndex, option) { // a second loop that check if the option value starts with the filter value
    if ($(option).val().startsWith(value))
      $(option).clone().appendTo($("#kuarter"));
  });

});
});
});
</script>
```

This is the HTML code for the dropdowns:

```
<tr valign="baseline">
  <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">Kawasan:</td>
  <td><select name="pilih_kawasan" id="kawasan">
  <option value="none">SILA PILIH</option>
<option value="kuching">KUCHING</option>
<option value="lundu">LUNDU</option>
<option value="sriaman">SRI AMAN</option>
<option value="betong">BETONG</option>
</select></td>
</tr>
<tr valign="baseline">
  <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">Kuarter:</td>
  <td><select name="pilih_kuarter" id="kuarter">
  <option value="none-01"></option>
<option value="kuching-01">JALAN DURIAN BURONG STAMPIN</option>
<option value="lundu-01">JALAN SEKETI</option>
<option value="sriaman-01">JALAN FOO CHOW</option>
<option value="sriaman-02">JALAN SABU</option>
<option value="betong-01">JALAN TANJUNG ASSAM</option>
</select></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: can you post your code in plunker or something?

Comment: And could you explain the results what you want and what you got more specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that you are saving the `value` of the selected option in `#kuarter`, and not the text that's displayed in the e.g. the value for the option you are selecting is `kuching-01`:

```
<option value="kuching-01">JALAN DURIAN BURONG STAMPIN</option>
```

As other code depends on the value, you can't change the option value to match the text you want.

What we can do instead is save the text in a hidden input that will get submitted with the form. For this to work, the input has to have the same name as the option currently has, so that your processing code will recognise it.

To do this we need to:

1. Change the name of the select so that our new hidden input can use the name `pilih_kawasan` and sumbit the value for processing, e.g. `<select name="pilih_kawasan_select" id="kawasan">`
2. Add a hidden input to your form with the name `pilih_kawasan` to store the text, e.g.: `<input type="hidden" name="pilih_kawasan" id="pilih_kawasan_value" value="">`
3. Add javascript function to update the value of the hidden field `#pilih_kawasan_value` with the selected *text* (i.e. not *value*).
4. Call this function every time the #kuarter dropdown changes. This needs to be done in 2 places: when a new value is selected in `#kuarter`, and also when the value of 'kawasan' changes (because that changes the values in `#kuarter`).

**Working snippet**

The HTML & jQuery below are working here, run the snippet to see what its doing.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var $options = $("#kuarter").clone(); 

  $("#kawasan").change(function() {
    var filters = [];
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
      $(this).find("option").each(function(index, option) {
        if ($(option).val() != "")
          filters.push($(option).val());
      });
    } else {
      filters.push($(this).val())
    }
    $("#kuarter").html("");

    $.each(filters, function(index, value) {
      $options.find("option").each(function(optionIndex, option) { 
        if ($(option).val().startsWith(value)) {
          $(option).clone().appendTo($("#kuarter"));

          // (4.) ADDED: the #kuarter values have changed, so update the hidden input to the selected text
          selected_text = $("#kuarter option:selected").text(); // get the text from the selected option
          setKuarterValue(selected_text); // call our function to update the hidden input

        }
      });
    });
  });

    // (4.) ADDED: Update the hidden input any time the #kuarter dropdown is changed
  $("#kuarter").change(function() {
    // get the text from the selected option in #kawasan
    selected_text = $("#kuarter option:selected").text();
    setKuarterValue(selected_text); // call our function to update the hidden input
  });

});

/* (3.) function to set the values of the hidden input "#pilih_kuarter"
   that will be submitted to your processing code. */
function setKuarterValue(myval) {
    // if the value hasn't changed , no need to update
    if ($("#pilih_kuarter").val() == myval) return;

    // set the value of the hidden input with the selected text
    $("#pilih_kuarter").val(myval);

     // just for testing, so we can see the value that will be submitted - delete when its working for you
    console.log ("Set pilih_kuarter value = "+ myval);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr valign="baseline">
    <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">Kawasan:</td>
    <td>

      <!-- (1.) UPDATED: Change the name of the select, as we're going to submit our hidden input using this name instead -->

      <select name="pilih_kawasan" id="kawasan">
                <option value="none">SILA PILIH</option>
                <option value="kuching">KUCHING</option>
                <option value="lundu">LUNDU</option>
                <option value="sriaman">SRI AMAN</option>
                <option value="betong">BETONG</option>
            </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr valign="baseline">
    <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">Kuarter:</td>
    <td>
      <select name="pilih_kuarter_select" id="kuarter">
                <option value="none-01"></option>
                <option value="kuching-01">JALAN DURIAN BURONG STAMPIN</option>
                <option value="lundu-01">JALAN SEKETI</option>
                <option value="sriaman-01">JALAN FOO CHOW</option>
                <option value="sriaman-02">JALAN SABU</option>
                <option value="betong-01">JALAN TANJUNG ASSAM</option>
            </select>
    </td>
  </tr>

 <!-- (2.) ADDED: add a new hidden input to store the required text
      this must have the name=pilih_kuarter so it will submit the value to you database -->
  <input type="hidden" name="pilih_kuarter" id="pilih_kuarter" value="">

</table>
```

Comment: i do change the value but that page cannot display the value that I want.

Comment: @mirr if you change the value, then show us *that* code so we can see whats not working! We can't help if we don't have the code where the problem is.

Comment: @mirr OK, the value is being used elsewhere, changing the values won't wok in that case. How does the selected option get saved to the database - e.g. do you submit the values as a form?

Comment: @mirr I've updated my answer, the code in it works, but you'll need to make sure it works with your other code. Let me know how that goes for you.

Comment: wow..thanks a lot master..i do really appreciate your help..if u dont mind, can u explain the code that u changed because i dont really understand it..sorry for troubling you master..

Comment: Is it working for you now? I did try to explain the code in my answer, so I've updated it to use the numbers from the "To do this we need to:" list and add them to the code comments that match the explanations. But let me know if there's anything you still don't understand! And if the answer is solved your problem, don't forget to accept the answer to mark it as resolved on the site, and we'll both get some rep points :)

Comment: hello..i think u wrongly put the value of KAWASAN and value of KUARTER..please refer new answer that i posted...the value is iinverted..the KAWASAN's value should be in KUARTER's value and the KUARTER's value should in KAWASAN's value

Comment: @mirr I've updated the code, try that and see if it works now!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This is the result..the value in kuarter's should be in kawasan's value and the kawasan's value should in kuarter's value